How to get the linked issue of a project item using GitHub Webhook?
I’ve set up a webhook for projects_v2_item, and whenever I update an entry in the project, it triggers a request with the relevant details. However, while the request contains information about the project item itself, it does not include the linked issue.
How can I retrieve the linked issue from the webhook payload?
{
    "action": "edited",
    "projects_v2_item": {
        "id": 10000001,
        "node_id": "###",
        "project_node_id": "###",
        "content_node_id": "###",
        "content_type": "Issue",
        "creator": {
            "login": "sumedhe",
            "id": 2020370,
            "node_id": "###",
            ...
        },
        "created_at": "2024-10-01T08:29:55Z",
        "updated_at": "2024-10-01T08:31:44Z",
        "archived_at": null
    },
    "changes": {
        "field_value": {
            "field_node_id": "###",
            "field_type": "single_select",
            "field_name": "Status",
            "project_number": 1,
            "from": null,
            "to": {
                "id": "###",
                "name": "Todo",
                "color": "GREEN",
                "description": "This+item+hasn't+been+started"
            }
        }
    },
    "organization": {
        "login": "selforgmap",
        "id": 47916970,
        ...
    },
    "sender": {
        "login": "sumedhe",
        "id": 2020370,
        ...
    }
}

